$f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\} \to \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y^2=x^2+x^3\}$ s.t. $f(t)=(t^2-1,t^3-t)$ is bijective
Let be $X=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$, $Y=\{y^2=x^2+x^3\}$ and $f:X \to Y$ such that for all $t \in X$ we have $f(t)=(t^2-1, t^3-t)$
The exercise asks me to show that $f$ is continuous and bijective. Now $f$ is continuous because $x(t)=t^2-1$ and $y(t)=t^3-t$ are continuous.
Besides $f$ is injective because $\,\,\,x(t)=x(s)$ implies $\,\,t^2=s^2$ and $\,\,y(t)=y(s)$ implies $\,\,t(t^2-1)=s(s^2-1)=s(t^2-1)$ then $s=t$
I am stuck on the surjectivity, any hint?

To conclude $s=t$ you divided by $t^2-1$, but what happens if $t^2-1=0$?

Right! In that case $t=-1$ and $t^2=s^2$, so $s=-1$

Suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are such that $y^2=x^2+x^3$. Then $x\geqslant-1$; otherwise, $y^2=x^2(1+x)<0$, which is impossible. Since $x\geqslant-1$, $x+1\geqslant0$, and therefore $x+1=t^2$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$. Therefore$$y^2=x^2(x+1)=(t^2-1)t^2=(t^3-t)^2.$$So, $y=\pm(t^3-t)$. If $y$ and $t^3-t$ have the same sign, you are done. Otherwise,$$y=-(t^3-t)=(-t)^3-(-t).$$Unless, of course, if $t=-1$; then you cannot put $-t$ instead of $t$, since $1$ does not belong to the domain of $f$. But if $t=-1$, then $y=t^3-t=0$.

You used that for some points you need $t$ but on other cases you may need to change the sign and choose $-t$. What happens if $t=-1$ and you need to change the sign and take $t=1$, which is not on the domain?

@jjagmath That will not be necessary. The only case in which $t=-1$ is when $x=y=0$, in which case there will be no need to change the sign.

I know, the question was rhetorical to make the observation that your proof omitted that. Just like the OP omitted a detail and I observed that in a comment in the question. Both are related with the fact that the domain is $\Bbb R \setminus {1}$. I believe details are important in Mathematics.

@jjagmath I agree and I have edited my answer.
